# Show that a group of order $pq$ has subgroups of orders $p$ and $q$ without using Sylow’s and Cauchy’s theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $o(G)$ is $pq$, $p>q$ are primes, prove that $G$ has a subgroup of order $p$ and a subgroup of order $q$.

This question is from Herstein and it comes before Sylow’s and Cauchy’s theorem. So I’m expecting an answer without using any of these.

Here’s what I got so far:

If $G$ is cyclic, then we are done, otherwise we can assume that it is not cyclic, which means every non-identity element must be of order $p$ or $q$.

Case (1): if there exists $a \in G$ such that $o(a) = p$ and if there also exists an element of order $q$, then we are done. So we can assume that every non-identity element is of order $p$. Now pick $b \in G$ such that $b \notin \langle a \rangle$ then $o(b) = p$ and $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = \langle e \rangle$.

So we have $\langle a \rangle \langle b \rangle \subset G$ but $o(\langle a \rangle \langle b \rangle) = \dfrac {o(\langle a \rangle) o(\langle b \rangle)}{o(\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle)} = p^2$ but $p^2 > pq$ [since $p>q$] so we got a contradiction.

Give me a hint for the second case and correct me if my argument for the first case is wrong.

Comment: In general $\langle a\rangle\langle b\rangle$ is not a subgroup, but the subgroup generated by them has order at least what you suggest.

Comment: I didn't say that it's a subgroup, I only used it as a subset and that formula works for the product of two finite subgroups @DavidA.Craven

Comment: Your argument in the first case looks good to me.

Comment: @LucasHaobam OK, yes. It's just a subset. It's fine, but is not the way you are supposed to do it, as it doesn't work for the other prime.

Comment: Okay, give me a hint. I'll try @DavidA.Craven

Comment: There is an answer with a hint.

Comment: Hint: If all the elements of the group are of $q$ order, what would the centralizers of these elements look like?

Comment: @UmeshShankar How do you easily see that those are not also just of order $q$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $p$ would divide the order of the group and the index of the centralizers.

Comment: @UmeshShankar Why should $p$ divide the index of the centralizer?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Because the centralizers are subgroups. You don't want them to be order $p$. Then, they should be of index $p$.

Comment: @UmeshShankar Right, sorry, I got myself confused with which prime was which here. So all of those subgroups are self-centralizing. Where does that lead?

Comment: I only mentioned the word centralizer to hint at a connection with the class equation.

Comment: @UmeshShankar Ahh, of course. I am apparently slow today. That is a good way to go about it.

Comment: This problem comes before class equations section so I'm searching for an elementary way @UmeshShankar

Comment: which will conclude that every $(N(a))$ will have order $q$ right? then? @UmeshShankar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that every non-identity element generates a cyclic group of order $q$, the smaller of the primes.

Conjugacy is an equivalence relation on a group. So, we should be able to partition the group into its equivalence classes. **The size of the equivalence class an element belongs to is the index of the centralizer of the element.** Why? Fix $x\in G$. Make a homomorphism from $G \rightarrow G$ by sending $g \rightarrow xgx^{-1}$. The size of the equivalence class is the order of the image. What is the kernel of this map?

If the centralizer is of order $p$ or $pq$, we are done. Assume every centralizer is of order $q$, the index of the centralizer is $pq/q=p$. Every element would belong in a equivalence class of size $p$, except for the identity element.

A simple cardinality calculation shows that $pq= kp+1$, where represents the number of equivalence classes. However, this is absurd and therefore, not every subgroup is of order $q$.

Comment: This works for both cases

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if all the non-trivial elements of $G$ have order $pq$, then, for any given $g\in G\setminus\{e\}$, we get $e=g^{pq}=(g^p)^q$ and hence $o(g^p)\mid q$; but $g^p\in G\setminus\{e\}$, so, by assumption, $o(g^p)=pq$ and we end up with $pq\mid q$: contradiction. Therefore, there must be elements of order $p$ *and/or* elements of order $q$. If $G$ is Abelian, then your argument works for the "second case" either, because then every subgroup is normal and hence $\langle a\rangle\langle b\rangle$ *is* a subgroup of $G$ such that $o(\langle a \rangle \langle b \rangle) = \dfrac {o(\langle a \rangle)o(\langle b \rangle)}{o(\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle)} = q^2\nmid pq$: contradiction (Lagrange). So, there must be elements of both orders, $p$ *and* $q$. If $G$ is nonabelian, then it has trivial center (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4185478/943729)) and the Class Equation reads:
$$pq=1+k_pp+k_qq$$
where $k_i$ are the number of conjugacy classes of size $i$. None of the $k_i$ can be zero, because neither $p\nmid 1$ nor $q\nmid 1$. Say $O_p$ a conjugacy class of size $p$ and $O_q$ a conjugacy class of size $q$, which as said both exist; for $g\in O_p$, we get $|C_G(g)|=q$ (Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem) and hence $\langle g\rangle=C_G(g)$ (because in general $\langle g\rangle\le C_G(g)$) and finally $o(g)=q$. Likewise, for $h\in O_q$, we get $|C_G(h)|=p$ and hence $\langle h\rangle=C_G(h)$ and $o(h)=p$.

Comment: You are trying to prove that $G$ has elements of orders $p$ and $q$. Certainly if $G$ has an element of order $pq$ then powers of it have order $p$ and $q$. So your only issue is if all non-trivial elements have order $p$, or all have order $q$. Which you don't appear to address.

Comment: @David A. Craven, The OP has proved that *not all* the non-trivial elements have order $p$. With a similar argument, *in the case of Abelian $G$*, I (think to) have proved that not all the non-trivial elements have order $q$. So the Abelian case is done. Then, I dealt with the nonabelian case separately, as a whole, with the Class Equation. Is my logic flawn somewhere?

Comment: The main part of your solution is the statement that, for a non-abelian group, the centralizer of an element of order $p$ has order $p$, and similarly for $q$. Once you state that, which is just half a line, then everything else follows immediately. You seem to have buried the pertient part with lots of other things. For the abelian case, the proof is very fast.

Comment: Here is the proof. Assume $p\neq q$, but to make statements quicker, do not assume $p>q$. If $G$ has an element $x$ of order $pq$ then $x^p$ has order $q$, $x^q$ has order $p$, and done. So all elements have order $1$ or $p$, or $1$ and $q$. Let $x$ be an element of order $p$. If $G$ is abelian then $H=\langle x\rangle$ is normal, and $G/H$ has order $q$. Let $Hy$ have order $q$ in $G/H$. Then $y$ cannot have order $p$, because its image has order $q$. Done.

Comment: If $G$ is non-abelian then $G/Z(G)$ cannot have prime order, and $G\neq Z(G)$, so $Z(G)=1$. In particular, any element of order $p$ has centralizer of order exactly $p$. Thus if $G$ has no elements of order $q$ and $c$ classes of order $p$ (each of which as size $q$), then $|G|=pq=1+cq$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

**Case $G$ abelian**. If $G$ has all the nontrivial elements of one same order, say $p$, then there are $k=\frac{pq-1}{p-1}\ge2$ distinct subgroups of order $p$. Call $H$ and $K$ two of them. The set $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^2$: contradiction, because $p\nmid q$. Same conclusion if $G$ has all the nontrivial elements of order $q$, as $q\nmid p$. So, $G$ has elements of both orders $p$ and $q$.

**Case $G$ nonabelian**. Then $pq=1+kp+mq$ is the only possible class equation, for some *positive* integers $l$ and $m$, and hence $G$ has subgroups (centralizers, actually) of both orders $p$ and $q$.